# How to build QField source

Tags: qfield

I ran https://github.com/opengisch/QField build for Android using Powershell with the following steps:

1. Install docker for Windows
2. Execute Pull command at https://hub.docker.com/r/opengisch/qfield-sdk/tags/
3. Run [git clone https://github.com/opengisch/QField.git] to download the source locally
4. Execute [cd QField] and move to the downloaded folder
5. Run [git submodule init]
6. Run [git submodule update]
7. Run [docker run -v $(pwd):/usr/src/qfield docker.io/opengisch/qfield-sdk:$TAG /usr/src/qfield/scripts/docker-build.sh --rm] , Enter the 2 QField SDK tags in "$TAG"

I get the error

> ERROR MISSING APP_VERSION OR APP_VERSION_CODE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE

What kind of settings are needed to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The build section of QField suggests using the build.sh script

https://github.com/opengisch/QField/blob/master/doc/dev.md

```
./scripts/build.sh
```